# Remove an Extra Entry for Windows 7 in BURG or GRUB?

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, windows-7, burg

For some reason I have two entries for the same copy of Windows 7 in burg (and before I installed burg, there were two in the grub menu as well). They are on different partitions but they boot into the same Windows. I think one is the recovery partition maybe. But they are both the same. I would just like to remove one of them so I have a clean boot screen with one Ubuntu and one Windows option. I figured out how to take the Ubuntu recovery mode  off of the list, but I think the Windows problem is too complicated for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely try this new application, it's called Grub Organizer. Here's its Launchpad page: https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer .

Comment: You are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this post :

[How to change the menu order of BURG](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7569/how-to-change-the-menu-order-of-burg)